# How can I select dbt models by `meta` field?

Tags: sql, dbt

I am trying to figure out how and if I can select `dbt` model by their `meta` field?

My `dbt` model documentation `yaml` file looks as follows:

```
 - name: my_table
    description: my table description
    meta:
      owner:
        - Analytics
    config:
      tags:
        - common
...
```

Now, I can select models by the defined tag with the command below:

```
dbt ls --select tag:common --resource-type model
```

Now, I would like to know how I can select models using the `meta` field information?

I tried the following, but this didn't work.

```
dbt ls --select meta.owner:Analytics
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`meta` properties are under `config` so you should be able select them like this example:

`dbt ls --select config.meta.owner:"team1"`